# Nvcc without GPU

Tags: shell, cuda, computer-vision

I'm trying to get a region proposals from faster-RCNN.
I'd found this nice and neat repo in the github, but whenever I executed shell command, `sh make.sh`, it spits out a 
`cffi.error.VerificationError: LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` error, which I never heard of. When I searched for it, it seems to be related with wrong `CUDA_ARCH` settings, but I don't have GPU in my local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/

export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/
#You may also want to ad the following
#export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/cuda/include

export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
export CFLAGS="-std=c99"

python setup.py build_ext --inplace
rm -rf build

CUDA_ARCH="-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
       -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
       -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
       -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
       -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
       -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 "

# compile NMS
cd model/nms/src
echo "Compiling nms kernels by nvcc..."
nvcc -c -o nms_cuda_kernel.cu.o nms_cuda_kernel.cu \
-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC $CUDA_ARCH

cd ../
python build.py

# compile roi_pooling
cd ../../
cd model/roi_pooling/src
echo "Compiling roi pooling kernels by nvcc..."
nvcc -c -o roi_pooling.cu.o roi_pooling_kernel.cu \
-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC $CUDA_ARCH
cd ../
python build.py

# compile roi_align
cd ../../
cd model/roi_align/src
echo "Compiling roi align kernels by nvcc..."
nvcc -c -o roi_align_kernel.cu.o roi_align_kernel.cu \
-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC $CUDA_ARCH
cd ../
python build.py

# compile roi_crop
cd ../../
cd model/roi_crop/src
echo "Compiling roi crop kernels by nvcc..."
nvcc -c -o roi_crop_cuda_kernel.cu.o roi_crop_cuda_kernel.cu \
-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC $CUDA_ARCH
cd ../
python build.py
```

I've searched for how to compule `CUDA` code without GPU, but it didn't give me the perfect solution. I also erased the `CUDA_ARCH`, and sets `GOOGLE_CUDA` to `0`, but it all failed. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You should include the relevant error messages, because gcc failing doesn't say anything. Above the gcc failed with exit status 1 message you should see more messages pointing to the actual error. In doubt, include a link to the complete build log.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get this to *build* without GPU. That's not very useful, though. The `nvcc` compiler generates GPU code, so you couldn't run that generated code anyway.

Having said that, for others that stumble on the same question: you can achieve this by installing CUDA [meta-packages](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-metas), in particular the compiler and development libraries, but not the driver and runtimes.